# Unwanted MySQLi connection error message (PHP)

Tags: php, mysqli, connection, message

When I'm connecting to MySQL using the mysqli class constructor I get an echoed error message from PHP when I don't provide the correct connection details. However, there is an appropriate way to deal with errors, like connect_errno and connect_error, but PHP always seems to echo the fact that a connection was unsuccessful whereas I want to deal with any errors manually.

Comment: what does it say / what is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ini_set('display_errors', FALSE);
```

Comment: So I have to turn off all errors, just to get rid of this one?

Comment: Yes, sure, you have to turn off displaying all the errors on a live site, not only one.